# Matching a specific string between two forward slashes

Tags: regex

I need to find all %20's between two forward slashes.

```
example.com/book%20/picture1.jpg
example.com/book%20/picture2.jpg
example.com/book%20/picture3.jpg
example.com/pages/picture%20book1.jpg
example.com/pages/picture%20book2.jpg
example.com/pages/picture%20book3.jpg
```

It should find the first 3 links, not the last 3.

I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: show your current code, please.

Comment: Maybe because the last three ones aren’t between two forward slashes?

Answer (score 3):

This fulfills the requirement "%20" between two forward slashes

```
/\/[^/]*%20[^/]*\//

\/       literal "/"
[^/]*    every character except for a slash, zero or more occurences
%20      literal "%20"
[^/]*    every character except for a slash, zero or more occurences
\/       literal "/"
```

Such an RE could be used for validating, if used for matching it matches the text between two slashes with a `%20` including the leading and trailing slash.

Comment: im trying to use this in UltraEdit and it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Translated according to http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/regular_expressions.html: `/[~/]++^%20[~/]++/`

Comment: thats very close! Its carrying over to the next line though until it hits another forward slash....

Comment: scratch that, i added a different tag to the end and its working! MUCH thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a regex implemenation that supports arbitrarily long lookaround constructs (like .NET) you could use

```
(?<=.*/)%20(?=.*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one in .Net and it returned the three first links. I am not much of a regex guy, so this can most likely be done much more elegant way than my example.

```
(\w*\.*)*/(\w*)*%20(\w*)*/(\w*\.*)*
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lekensteyn was right but skipped escaping forward slashes in the character class `[^/]*`.

Instead of:

```
/\/[^/]*%20[^/]*\//
```

use:

```
/\/[^\/]*%20[^\/]*\//
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question.